# Algorithms, DFS

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

I've written a program to find shortest path in a N*N grid recursively.

```
def dfs(x,y,Map,p):
    N = len(Map)
    p += [[x,y]]
    if Map[x][y] == 'E':
        return p

    for i in [[x-1,y],[x+1,y],[x,y-1],[x,y+1]]:
        if N > i[0] >= 0 and N > i[1] >= 0 :
            if (Map[i[0]][i[1]] == 'P' or Map[i[0]][i[1]] == 'E')  and i not in p:
                dfs(i[0], i[1], Map,p)
    return []
```

When Map[x][y] = 'E' the recursion don't stop and return p. But it goes till the end. How to correct it and return the path(p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, the code is prone to loop indefinitely. This is due to lack of checks whether you've entered a node before and moving in all (4) directions from a given node.

To solve it simply, add another array NxN of Boolean values answering the question: `visited?`. Then update the code to something along the lines:

```
def dfs(x,y,Map,visited,p):
    visited[x,y] = true;
    N = len(Map)
    (...)
    if (Map[i[0]][i[1]] == 'P' or Map[i[0]][i[1]] == 'E')  
        and i not in p
        and visited[i[0], i[1]] == false:
        dfs(i[0], i[1], Map,visited,p)
```